# Why is the Java API for XML Processing (JAXP) bundled with Java 7 not working?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, tomcat, sax

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE starfleet SYSTEM "http://localhost:8080/xml-validate/dtd/starfleet.dtd">
<starfleet>
    <title>The two most famous starships in the fleet</title>
    <starship name="USS Enterprise" sn="NCC-1701">
        <class name="Constitution"/>
        <captain>James Tiberius Kirk</captain>
    </starship>

    <starship name="USS Enterprise" sn="NCC-1701-D">
        <class name="Galaxy"/>
        <captain>Jean-Luc Picard</captain>
    </starship>
</starfleet>
```

And the following DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT starfleet (title,starship*)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT starship (class,captain)>
<!ATTLIST
    starship name CDATA #REQUIRED
    sn CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT class EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST class name CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT captain (#PCDATA)>
```

I wanted to parse and validate the XML by using JAXP and a simple JSP file.

My SAX Exception Handler is:

```
package myPkg;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

public class ParsingExceptionHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    public SAXParseException parsingException = null;
    public String errorLevel = null;

    public void warning(SAXParseException e) {
        errorLevel = "Warning";
        parsingException = e;
    }

    public void error(SAXParseException e) {
        errorLevel = "Error";
        parsingException = e;
    }

    public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) {
        errorLevel = "Fatal error";
        parsingException = e;
    }
}
```

And the JSP file that executes the actual validation is:

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser"%>
<%@page import="org.xml.sax.InputSource"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils"%>
<%@page import="myPkg.ParsingExceptionHandler"%>
<html><head><title>Starfleet validation (SAX - DTD)</title></head><body>
<%
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setValidating(true);
    SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource("webapps/xml-validate/xml/enterprises.xml");
    ParsingExceptionHandler handler = new ParsingExceptionHandler();

    try {
        parser.parse(inputSource, handler);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println("Something went wrong...");
    }

    if (handler.errorLevel == null) {
        out.println("The document is valid.");
    } else {
        out.println(
            "*** Validation " + handler.errorLevel + ": "
            + StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(handler.parsingException.toString())
        );
    }
%>
</body></html>
```

The problem is that no matter what I do, the **catch** part of the code is entered, which means that my XML file is never deemed "valid" by the parser. Something must be wrong with my XML, right? However, the Exception Handler is never used and so its **parsingException** and **errorLevel** attributes always remain null, causing the message *"The document is valid"* to be displayed in the browser. Any insight into why is this happening?

P.S.: This is running inside a Tomcat instance.

Comment: The first thing you should do is to add `e.printStackTrace()` into the `catch` block, to see **what exactly** went wrong.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek I inspected catalina.out and found the root of the issue. I will place it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the path I used inside my JSP file to refer to the location of the XML file was not correct.

I had put:

```
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource("webapps/xml-validate/xml/enterprises.xml");
```

Erroneously assuming that this relative path would resolve to Tomcat's installation directory... but Tomcat actually resolved it (on my computer running OS X) to:

```
~/dev/apache-tomcat/bin/webapps/xml-validate/xml/enterprises.xml
```

*Notice the introduction of the **bin** directory above.*

So, all I had to do was to change the given path to:

```
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource("../webapps/xml-validate/xml/enterprises.xml");
```

And the XML was successfully found.